# How do I display the error message only when min and max value exist?

Tags: javascript

I have created a function that return the min and max value, if the  user selects" between" or just the min or max based on the operator the user selects.

When the user selects the "between" operator and enters the MIN value, it displays and error msg even when the min value is positive and is a number.. I want it to only display the error message on;y after the max value is enter and only if the max value is incorrect.

How can I display the error message Only when both min and max are entered.. incorrectly.

```
   function minmaxval(min, max, op) {
            var rVal = "",
                msg = "",
                errormsg = "Enter a Max Value larger then Min Value and all number should be greater then 0!",
                errormsg2 = "Enter a  number greater then  0!";
            if (operator === "between") {
                if (this.getNumber(min) !== false && this.getNumber(max) !== false && (min < max) && (min > 0)) {
                    displayMessage(min, max, msg);
                    rVal = "(" + min + " - <span class='truncate'> " + max + "</span>)";
                } else {
                  if((min!="")&&(max!="") &&(min>max)) {
                    displayMessage(min, max, errormsg);
                    rVal = "";
                   }
                }
            } 
            return rVal    ;
        }

  displayMessage(min,max,msg) {

      document.getElementByID("#err").innerHTML=msg;
)
```

Comment: I understood what you want. I'm asking what you see as a problem?  Do you understand every line of this code?

Comment: The problem I see is it not displaying  the error message correctly  not sure where I am doing wrong

Comment: Why are **you** (by yourself) not able to change this code in a way you describe?  Have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i had tried and I am stuck now..

Comment: Can you also post displayMessage() function?

Comment: **Show** what you've tried and **explain** where you are stuck.

Comment: I added the displayMessage it just add the error message nothing much

Answer (score 0):

Within your `operator === "between"` block, find this:

```
if (this.getNumber(min) !== false && this.getNumber(max) !== false && (min < max) && (min > 0)) {
```

...and change it to this:

```
if (   (this.getNumber(min) && min > 0) 
    || (this.getNumber(min) && this.getNumber(max) && min < max)
) {
```

In your posted code you're requiring both `getNumber(min)` and `getNumber(max)` to be true in order for your first condition to execute, instead of displaying an error message. Change that so your first condition will execute if EITHER `getNumber(min)` is `true` and `min` is greater than `0` OR both are `true` and `min` is less than `max`. Be sure to include the parenthesis so the operators are evaluated in the proper order.